# jquery mobile data-native-menu=false not working on iOS,

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, multi-select

I am try to use custom multiselect on iOS, using jquery mobile 1.3.2, but when I set the flag data-native-menu=false, nothing happens, no native select is used, and certainly no custom select pops up, nothing. here is the code

```
<select name="poimain_category_select" id="poimain_category_select" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false" data-placeholder="true"">
                    <option id="poinmain_category_select_holder" value=""><%print(T('SELECT_CATEGORY'))%></option>
                        <%print(poidata['category_data'])%>
                    </select>
```

Comment: I have the same issue with 1.3.2 older version code works perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with tapHold. I added "-button" to my id when binding and it worked.

From HTML-file:

```
<select id="selectVaapen" data-native-menu="false"  data-inline="false">
    <!-- Empty -->
</select>
```

From javascript-file:

```
$(function() {
    $("#selectVaapen-button").bind('taphold', function(event) {
        console.log("tapholdHandler");
    });
});
```